# Google Chrome: JavaScript Error Message 

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When using Google Chrome, I receive the following error message:

Error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

It occurs directly after my doctype declaration at the top of my HTML page

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Any ideas what this JavaScript error message is? It only seems to occur with Google Chrome (works fine in Safari, Firfox and IE)

Comment: Can you produce a small reduction? If so please submit a bug report to  http://crbug.com/new and let me know the bug number so I can send it to proper people.

Answer (score 14):

This problem occurred for me when I was using JQuery to load in HTML from an XMLHTTPRequest that was HTML, but the mime type was text/javascript.

So for example, I had some code such as:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    data:'params=here',
    success:function(request) {
        jQuery('#country_list_container').html(request);
    },
    type:'get',
    url:'/getHtml'
});
```

jQuery is sending a request to getHtml, and getHtml is returning a simple snippet of HTML, with a mime/type however of `"text/javascript"`. The reason the `getHtml` action was returning `text/javascript` is because the accept header of the request from jQuery is:

```
"Accept:text/javascript, text/html, application/xml, text/xml, */*"
```

So, all I had to do was force a header of `text/html` and everything worked perfectly.

The parse error you are seeing is a result of Javascript trying to eval the content.

Comment: Are you able to supply an example of the code edited with the force header change?

Comment: I think you are meaning this one `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');`

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was caused by an `eval()` statement aborting. When I fixed the problem the error message disappeared.

At the present time (June 2010) Chrome Javascript has a buggy `eval()` statement. `eval()` will abort without issuing an error message if a variable in the `eval()` statement has been assigned the reserved word '`delete`'. It took me almost a week to uncover this bug because `eval()` aborts without any warning or error message, and the abort has nasty side-effects.

I was using `eval()` to achieve this result: obj.delete = somevalue.

This code will cause an eval() abort:

```
var obj = new Object();
var x = 'delete';
var y = 2;
eval('obj.' + x + ' = y');
```

This code works:

```
var obj = new Object();
var x = 'delete';
var y = 2;
eval('obj[\'' + x + '\'] = y');
```

In summary, don't use `eval()` to construct `obj.delete = somevalue`. Use `eval()` to construct the equivalent statement `obj["delete"] = somevalue`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the HTTP content type is not `text/html` or `application/xhtml+xml`?

Comment: I would I determine the HTTP content type?

Answer (score 1):

I found this Google Groups question.

Some others are experiencing the problem but without resolution.

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=7e9f87870a37e401&hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Try switching the order of your css and js declarations. Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you are returning a response to an ajax request in JSON, make sure you use `'application/json'` for the Content-Type.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of dredging up an old thread (I figure its better to keep all the info in one place), Chrome is still throwing these errors it seems.  I got the following while developing a site and tried all kinds of things with the page JS and PHP to get rid of it.  The error I got was:

```
error in event handler for 'undefined': SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
chrome/EventBindings:183
```

Eventually while checking code validity in FireFox I stumbled across the answer as a warning that there was a `'&'` in some text that should be converted to `'&amp;'` - once this was done the Chrome error went away.

Steve

Comment: To extend this, data from a db query with '&'s in it will also cause this error...

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem when I was trying to set `.innerHTML` dynamically generated with php (it was generated multi-line).

Replacing new line characters by spaces solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Rails App check that the format.js is in the response_to block.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this error in Chrome Dev Tools, and my cause was similar to Matthew O'Riordan's except it wasn't the Accept MIME-type but rather the broken AJAX URL.

I had rearranged my folder structure and forgot to update the URL; once I fixed the URL, the Dev Tools JS Error was gone.
Hope this helps!  :)